# How to partition an external hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have an external hard drive, and I want to make it into some separate partitions.

I tried to do that using my Windows 7, but can't find how.
[image]

Comment: @Luke: Upvote for the edit. WD drives are not partitioned differently.

Comment: @TFM yes, correct, I thought it is different

Comment: @TFM Thanks, but my answer wasn't selected :P Thanks anyways though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to delete the volume. Then down in the bottom where all of the partitions listed you can create new partitions. NOTE: Deleting the volume will delete all of the files on the HDD.

This should help you: [Create and format a hard disk partition](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Create-and-format-a-hard-disk-partition)

Answer (score 2):

The Shrink option appears under the following conditions:

1. It is not the boot drive, system drive, page file, or Crash Dump drive
2. It is formatted as NTFS
3. There are movable files at the end of the volume
4. It is a dynamic disk

Comment: "There are movable files at the end of the volume" - In this case you may have to delete files (if the hard drive is nearing full) and then run a disk defrag. Sometimes unmovable files appear at the end of the disk and can cause a bit of grief. Have a look here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/working-around-windows-vistas-shrink-volume-inadequacy-problems/